# Orders are being generated even after max number of orders is reached

Tags: php

Im writing a PHP scirpt that generates car orders of a random number until it reaches the max car order limit. The code works well on the first run but subsiqent runs it generates more cars than the max allowed. Generally about double of what i need, i've be been trying to figure this out for a while now but it keeps coming up with the same results.  Below is the code

```
foreach ($industries as $industry) {
    $indyId = $industry['id'];
    $cars = getIndyCars($conn, $indyId);
    //$lastOrderNumber = getLastOrderNumber($conn, $indyId);
    $orderNumber = generateOrderNumber($conn, $indyId);
    $industryOrders = [];

    foreach ($cars as $car) {

        $id = $car['id'];
        $maxCars = $car['maxCars'];
        $loaded = $car['loaded'];
        $x = 1;
        $typeId = $car['carType'];
        $carsAlreadyOrdered = getCarsOrderd($conn, $id);
        /*
        * CARS ARE ORDERED ON A RANDOM SCALE BETWWEN THE MAX CARS AND CARS ALREADY ORDERED THEY WILL KEEP ORDERING BETWEEN THE AMOUNT OF CARS LEFT AND THE MAX CARS
        * EVENTUALLY ORDERES WILL BE PLACED ON A SCHEDULE BUT THAT WILL COME LATER. 
        */
        if ($carsAlreadyOrdered < $maxCars) {
        $remainingCars = $maxCars - $carsAlreadyOrdered;
        $remainingCars -= $carsOrdered;
        $carsOrdered = rand(0, $remainingCars);
        
if ($carsOrdered + $remainingCars > $maxCars) {
            $carsOrdered = 0;
        }
        $carOrders = [];
        

        echo '<b>' . $carsOrdered . ' Cars ordered for '.$id.'</b> '.$remainingCars.' left<br>';
        if ($carsOrdered !== 0) {
            $carsOrdered = $carsAlreadyOrdered + $carsOrdered;
            updateCarsOrdered($conn, $id, $carsOrdered);
        }else{
        updateCarsOrdered($conn, $id, $carsOrdered);
        }
        $filterCars = getLocalFilterCars($conn, $typeId, $indyId);

        if (is_array($filterCars) && count($filterCars) > 0) {
            echo "<td>";
            for ($x = 0; $x < $carsOrdered; $x++) {
                $randomCarIndex = mt_rand(0, count($filterCars) - 1);
                $randomCar = $filterCars[$randomCarIndex];
                //echo $randomCar['filteredCars'];
                $carId=$randomCar['filteredCars'];
                $carWeight = 0;

                if ($loaded == 1) {
                    $payload = getCarPayload($cdbconn, $randomCar['filteredCars']);
                    $carLoad = rand(1, $payload);
                    $carWeight = $carLoad;
                    $totalLoadWgt = (int)$totalLoadWgt + (int)$carLoad;
                } elseif ($loaded == 0) {
                    $tareWeight = getCarEmptyWeight($cdbconn, $randomCar['filteredCars']);
                    $carWeight = $tareWeight;
                    $totalEmptyWeight = (int)$totalEmptyWeight + (int)$tareWeight;
                }
                addOrder($conn, $orderNumber, $indyId, $id, $carId, $loaded, $carWeight);
               /* $carOrders[] = [
                    'car' => $randomCar['filteredCars'],
                    'loaded' => $loaded,
                    'payload' => $carWeight
                ];*/
            }
        }

/*        if (!empty($carOrders)) {
            $industryOrders[] = [
                'industryTypeId' => $id,
                'orders' => $carOrders
            ];
        }*/
    }//IF MAX CARS ORDERED
    else{
        echo "No cars ordered for".$id."<br>";
    }

    }//CarForeach*/

    if (!empty($industryOrders)) {
        ///$jsonIndustryOrders = json_encode($industryOrders);
        //addOrder($conn, $indyId, $id, $carId, $loaded, $carWeight);
        //addOrder($conn, $indyId, $jsonIndustryOrders);
    }
}
```

Functions - The first function gets the current car count from the database and the secound updates the car cound hen the order is generated.

```
function getCarsOrderd($conn, $indyId){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM industry_cars WHERE id =?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
 if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("location: details.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
 }
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $indyId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)){
        return $row['carsOrdered'];
    }else{
        $result = false;
        return $result;
}
}
function updateCarsOrdered($conn, $indyId, $carsOrdered){
        $sql = "UPDATE industry_cars SET carsOrdered = ? WHERE id=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
 if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("location: ../details.php?error=stmtfailed");//ssssss
        exit();
 }
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $carsOrdered, $indyId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
function getIndustryOrders($conn, $indyId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM industryorders WHERE industryId = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
 if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("location: details.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
 }
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $indyId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_all($resultData, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comment this line `$remainingCars -= $carsOrdered;` and try again, it seems that you're trying to substract from a variable that's not yet defined on the code.

Comment: It's still ordering too many cars

Comment: Right, i'll try to give another approach.

Comment: Poorly/Inconsistently tabbed code is hard for you and reviewers to read.

Comment: What will happen if you change this ```$remainingCars -= $carsOrdered;``` to ```$carsAlreadyOrdered += $carsOrdered;```?? As I see here, you're generating new orders as long as the number of cars already ordered is less than the maximum number of cars but, you're not updating the number of cars already ordered inside this condition. This means that once the maximum number of cars has been reached, new orders will still be generated because ```$carsAlreadyOrdered``` is not updated, and the condition ```$carsAlreadyOrdered < $maxCars``` will still be **TRUE**.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are applying some sort of logic, generating a random number of cars, but you're not stablishing a limit, you can try to use a `for` loop with a random probability set, to ensure you'll have a limit, and a more realistic behavior.

Let's then change the logic, you can try this approach instead:

```
foreach ($cars as $car) {
    $id = $car['id'];
    $maxCars = $car['maxCars'];
    $loaded = $car['loaded'];
    $x = 1;
    $typeId = $car['carType'];
    $carsAlreadyOrdered = getCarsOrderd($conn, $id);


    if ($carsAlreadyOrdered < $maxCars) {
    $remainingCars = $maxCars - $carsAlreadyOrdered;
    $carsOrdered = rand(0, $remainingCars);
    if ($carsAlreadyOrdered < $maxCars) {
        $remainingCars = $maxCars - $carsAlreadyOrdered;
        $probability = rand(0, 100) / 100; // Set a random probability
        
        for ($i = 0; $i < $remainingCars; $i++) {
            if (rand(0, 100) / 100 < $probability) { // So, if the number is lees than the probability, +1 car
                $carsAlreadyOrdered++;
                updateCarsOrdered($conn, $id, $carsAlreadyOrdered);
            } else { // If more than the probability, stop.
                break;
            }
        }

        echo '<b>' . $carsAlreadyOrdered . ' Cars ordered for '.$id.'</b> '.$remainingCars.' left<br>';
        $filterCars = getLocalFilterCars($conn, $typeId, $indyId);

        if (is_array($filterCars) && count($filterCars) > 0) {
            echo "<td>";
            for ($x = 0; $x < $carsOrdered; $x++) {
                $randomCarIndex = mt_rand(0, count($filterCars) - 1);
                $randomCar = $filterCars[$randomCarIndex];
                //echo $randomCar['filteredCars'];
                $carId = $randomCar['filteredCars'];
                $carWeight = 0;

                if ($loaded == 1) {
                    $payload = getCarPayload($cdbconn, $randomCar['filteredCars']);
                    $carLoad = rand(1, $payload);
                    $carWeight = $carLoad;
                    $totalLoadWgt = (int)$totalLoadWgt + (int)$carLoad;
                } elseif ($loaded == 0) {
                    $tareWeight = getCarEmptyWeight($cdbconn, $randomCar['filteredCars']);
                    $carWeight = $tareWeight;
                    $totalEmptyWeight = (int)$totalEmptyWeight + (int)$tareWeight;
                }
                addOrder($conn, $orderNumber, $indyId, $id, $carId, $loaded, $carWeight);
                /* $carOrders[] = [
                    'car' => $randomCar['filteredCars'],
                    'loaded' => $loaded,
                    'payload' => $carWeight
                    ]; */
            }
        }
        
            /*if (!empty($carOrders)) {
                    $industryOrders[] = [
                    'industryTypeId' => $id,
                    'orders' => $carOrders
                    ];
                } */
    } //IF MAX CARS ORDERED
    else {
        echo "No cars ordered for" . $id . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to my issue I added some notes within the code. I believe it was an issue with the `$carsOrdered` variable being used to calculate the number of cars ordered and adding it on to the running total. I replaced that with `$runningCarsTotal` which seemed to fix this issue.

```
$region_id = 1;
$totalLoadWgt = "";
$totalEmptyWeight = "";

$industries = getIndustryList($conn, $region_id);

foreach ($industries as $industry) {
    $indyId = $industry['id'];
    $industry['industryName'];
    $cars = getIndyCars($conn, $indyId);
    $orderNumber = generateOrderNumber($conn, $indyId);
    echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>";
    echo $industry['industryName'];
    
    foreach ($cars as $car){

            $id = $car['id'];
            $maxCars = $car['maxCars'];
            $loaded = $car['loaded'];
            $x = 1;
            $typeId = $car['carType'];
         
            $carsAlreadyOrdered = getCarsOrderd($conn, $id); // Gets number of cars that have already been ordered
          
            $remainingCars = $maxCars - $carsAlreadyOrdered; // Calcualtes how many cars remain after previous order
        if ($carsAlreadyOrdered <= $maxCars) {
            $carsOrdered = rand(0, $remainingCars);
          
            $runningCarsTotal = $carsAlreadyOrdered+$carsOrdered; // Adds number of cars ordered to the running total
            updateCarsOrdered($conn, $id, $runningCarsTotal); // Updates database with new car count
        }
            $filterCars = getLocalFilterCars($conn, $typeId, $indyId);
        if (is_array($filterCars) && count($filterCars) > 0) {
                for ($x = 0; $x < $carsOrdered; $x++) {
                $randomCarIndex = mt_rand(0, count($filterCars) - 1);
                $randomCar = $filterCars[$randomCarIndex];
                $carId=$randomCar['filteredCars'];
                $carWeight = 0;

                if ($loaded == 1) {
                    $payload = getCarPayload($cdbconn, $randomCar['filteredCars']);
                    $carLoad = rand(1, $payload);
                    $carWeight = $carLoad;
                    $totalLoadWgt = (int)$totalLoadWgt + (int)$carLoad;
                } elseif ($loaded == 0) {
                    $tareWeight = getCarEmptyWeight($cdbconn, $randomCar['filteredCars']);
                    $carWeight = $tareWeight;
                    $totalEmptyWeight = (int)$totalEmptyWeight + (int)$tareWeight;
                }

                addOrder($conn, $orderNumber, $indyId, $id, $carId, $loaded, $carWeight); // Adds data to database with the above data added. 
                }
        }           
    }
}
```